# DelegatingSerializationFilter Could not set ObjectFilter: null warning message is repetitively appearing in console

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, keycloak

[image]

Not having any clue why is that.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
-Djdk.serialSetFilterAfterRead=true
```

See the following for more details

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-15901

> Seems like the problem is caused by ObjectInputStream.setObjectFilter
> (on Java 9 - 11) respective
> ObjectInputStream.setInternalObjectInputFilter (in Java 8) throws
> IllegalStateException("filter can not be set after an object has been
> read")

Comment: This works for me. Spring Boot 2.7.2, Keycloak adapters version 14.0.0. Running the spring boot app on JDK17

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't see the warnings after I did some changes. This is what I did in my pom.xml and made some changes to the Config class which extends the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
public class ResourceServerConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public final KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

// keycloakClientRequestFactory injected via constructor
public ResourceServerConfig(KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory) {
    this.keycloakClientRequestFactory = keycloakClientRequestFactory;
}

...
...
/**
 * To simplify communication between clients, Keycloak provides an extension of Spring’s RestTemplate that handles
 * bearer token authentication for you. To enable this feature your security configuration must add the
 * KeycloakRestTemplate bean. Note that it must be scoped as a prototype to function correctly.
 * <p>
 * Refer: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter (Spring Security Adapter)
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
    return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
}
}
```

And in the pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>12.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```